# How should be defined the options dictionary for PDFView usePageViewController withViewOptions:

Tags: ios, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

How should be defined a dictionary of options for a pageViewController for a PDFView from PDFKit?

> I am interested particulari with this flag
>
> UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation.horizontal

```
let pdfv = PDFView.init(frame: self.view.frame)

let opt = ?????

pdfv.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: opt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewOptions contains only 2 options: `interPageSpacing` and `spineLocation`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/optionskey

Exemple: `pdfv.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: ["interPageSpacing": 50])`

If you want to change the pageViewController direction to horizontal, use this code:

```
pdfv.displayDirection = .horizontal
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Carreful with those 2 lines with ios13 : I was settings the displayDirection to .horizontal but it kept showing in vertical mode...starting ios13 it seems you have to call pdf.usePageViewController(withViewOptions:) AFTER pdf.displayDirection setter.